# table design issue for normalizing multiple catogories sharing similar data

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I'm little confused in a table design.

Method 1) With first method i can select all phone number from phone_book table and filter out employee phone numbers by specifying type. 
Method 2) In second method i can select all by joining two table and can retrieve employee phone numbers.

I've same issue with addresses. I've address of employees, customers, staffs and others. I've googled and still cant choose which is right method. Which is the right method and why the other not and any other better design for this ?

**Method 1**

```
employee
id | name 
1      e


customer
id | name
1     c


phone_book
type | fk_id |     phone
  e      1         123123123
  c      1         451323123
```

**Method 2**

```
employee
id | name 
1      e


customer
id | name
1     c


employee_phone_book
emp_id  |     phone
   1         1231233434
   2         6273343423


customer_phone_book
cus_id  |  phone
   1       5231233434
   2       1251233434
```

Edit:
Employee and customers can have multiple phone numbers. And same with the address details.

Answer (score 0):

```
employee
id | name | phone_id
1      e    1


customer
id | name | phone_id
1     c     2


phone_book
phone_id |     phone
1         123123123
2         451323123
```

For me the reference to phone should be in the `employee` and `customer` tables (FK to the `phone_book` table)

UPDATE: If customer/employee may have multiple phones it would be better to define many-to-many relations via additional table e.g.

```
customer_phone 
phone_id |     customer_id (reference to the customer table)
1              1
2              1
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that employee and customers can have multiple phone numbers. And same with the address details.

Answer (score 0):

If employee and customers are having multiple phone numbers than your phone_book should look something like this. you need to create one is to many relation table structure.

```
phone_book
phone_id | EmpOrCustomer | EmpOrCustomerId | phone
1          1               1                  123123123
2          1               1                  45132XXXX
3          2               4                  45132XXXX
```

In the above table structure, you can add two additional column which tells you its employee or customer, another which tells what is the employee or customer id.

Hope this helps.